# Append left side panel dynamically to all pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm new to jQuery mobile and I'm developing an App using jQuery mobile 1.4.3. My problem is that I need to add a left side panel to all pages dynamically and I can't make it work.

The page also needs to have a left side header button on all pages, to access the panel menu.

my failed code attempt: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/claire89/yd1oze74/8/)

some sample code:

```
$(document).on('pagecontainerbeforeshow', function (e, ui) {
    var activePage = $(ui.toPage),
        activePageId = activePage[0].id,
        myPanel = "",
        panelBtn = "";

    //does not work, but you get the ideia:
    myPanel = $('<div data-role="panel" id="mypanel" data-theme="a"><li><a href="#page1" data-role="button" data-theme="a">Btn page 1</a></li><li><a href="#page2" data-role="button" data-theme="a">Btn page 2</a></li></div>');
    activePage.append(myPanel);

    //how to add the panel Button to the Header so that it will show the left panel? some dummy code:

    panelBtn = $('<a href="#mypanel" data-role="button" data-icon="bars" data-iconpos="notext"></a>');
    activePage.append(panelBtn);

    switch (activePageId) {
        case 'page1':

            break;
        case 'page2':

            break;
        default:
    }

}).on("pagecontainerhide", function (e, ui) {
    var activePage = $(ui.toPage),
        activePageId = activePage[0].id;
});
```

Comment: chek this http://jsfiddle.net/yd1oze74/10/

Answer (score -1):

try appending to `$(body)`

and im assuming that `pagecontainerbeforeshow` is a defined listener?